# How to take the average of specific different rows of a dataframe using Python

Tags: python

I now want to process a dataframe with the data as shown in the figure below. You can see that they have multi-column attributes. I now want to reduce the time resolution of the data. For example, take the average of the data in the red row in the figure as a new row of data, and average the data in the green row as another row of new data. , And finally get a new dataframe with a time resolution of 1 day. Your help is very important to me, thank you for any answer.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMYeE.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: you have red data in rows `2`, `2+15`, `2+15+15`, ... `2+15+15+15+...+15`.  The same with green data: `4`, `4+15`, `4+15+15`,..., `4+15+15+15+...+15`.  And you can use it in `while`-loop to get rows. OR you can use `modulo` on `index` - ie. `df[ (df.index-2) % 15 == 0 ]` or `df[ df.index % 15 == 2 ]`

Comment: OR maybe you need `.groupby('ut')` to work with different `UT` separatelly, and then you can use `.mean()` to calculate average for every group.

Comment: better put data as text in question so we could copy it and use it for tests. And you should show expected result.